# Is mining necessary for the transaction

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com

If someone doesn't want to mine, this means that they don't create coinbase transactions. Coinbase transactions are necessary for every transaction.

Can one spend their bitcoin without having to mine?

Answer (score 2):

Mining is necessary to *create* bitcoins, which happens with a coinbase transaction.  But they can be transferred from person to person after that without mining.  (Mining is still used to *confirm* those transactions, to ensure they cannot be reversed later; but the people making the transactions aren't responsible for that part of it.)

Think about the following analogy.  Regular money is created with a printing press.  But you yourself don't need a printing press in order to make transactions; somebody gives you money, and you give it to someone else.  Sure, at some time in the past, someone had to print that money, but that isn't your concern.

Comment: You are right but for every block or transaction, coinbase transaction is necessary which is not possible without mining

Comment: @RinkyGoyal Right, but it doesn't matter *who* mines.

Comment: @RinkyGoyal: For every **block**, yes.  For every **transaction**, no!  You don't need a coinbase to make a transaction.  When your transaction is confirmed by being included in a block, that block will contain a single coinbase transaction (created by someone else), but that block can contain a large number of ordinary transactions.